# Обращение дочернего окна к родительскому(Windows Forms Applications)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пытался обращаться из дочернего окна к родительскому, ничего не получилось... Прочитал, что можно в родительском прописать:

```
Form2^ form2 = gcnew Form2();
form2->Owner = this;
form2->ShowDialog();
form2->textBox1->Focus();
```

В дочернем обращаться так Owner->(как-бы указатель на родителя). Что-то я намутил, стало выдавать ошибку на Form2^ form2 = gcnew Form2(); такого рода:

error C3767: 'Server_WFA::Form2::Form2': candidate function(s) not accessible

Вроде ничего не менял... Правда был какой-то глюк(студия при открытии дочерней формы(графического представления) открывала родительскую форму, сейчас всё нормально, за исключением ошибки...)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было указать конструктору Форм2 публик...